# Asymptotic notation: How to prove that n^2 = Ω(nlogn)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I was asked to prove or disprove the following conjecture:

n^2 = Ω(nlogn)

This one feels like it should be very easy, and intuitively it seems to me that because Ω is a lower bound function, and n^2 is by definition of higher magnitude than nlogn, then it is also pretty obvious. However, I feel like this is not sufficient as a proof, or might be wrong...

For example, I know that anything that belongs to Ω(nlogn) can also belong to Ω(n) and Ω(logn), and all of them are <= n^2. Is this enough of a proof?

I have seen it given as an example to big Omega in several different places with no explanations as to why.

Here is my attempt to prove this conjecture after exploring HelpYou's answer:
[image: Proof #1]

Is this wrong? (P.S. - perhaps using T(n) is wrong here)

[image: Proof #2]

Hopefully this one is more accurate...

Comment: Unrelated to programming, your question is off-topic. Go to some computer scientist stack-exchange site, please.

Comment: Use the definition of Ω: f = Ω(g(n)) if and only if there exists a constant C and a number N such that for all n > N the following is true: f(n) >= C g(n)

Comment: @Barmaley.exe like so? (see my edited question)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Let's take:

```
f(n) = n^2

g(n) = n*logn

f(n) is in Ω(g(n)) if there is c > 0 and n0 > 0 such that:
f(n) >= c*g(n) for every n >= n0.
```

This means:

```
n*n >= c*n*logn          |:n ( n>=n0>0 )
n >= c*logn
```

Let's choose `c=1` and `n0=b^b` (b - the logarithm base, b > 1):

```
n >= logn
```

will be true for every `n>=n0` because `b^b >= b` when `b > 1`

**Method 2:**

```
          n*logn              logn      (*)        1/n *logb
   lim -------------- = lim ---------- ===== lim ------------ = 0
  n->inf   n^2         n->inf   n           n->inf    1
```

It could be demonstrated using l'Hospital (*). And that's all because the result is a finite value.

For the second method, the following table can be useful:

`f(n) = O/Ω/Ө(g(n))`

```
                      O                     Ω                     Ө
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       f(n)  
 lim --------       finite                > 0                 > 0 & finite
n->inf g(n)  

       g(n)  
 lim --------        > 0                 finite               > 0 & finite 
n->inf f(n)
```

Comment: Thank you. Method 2 sent me looking for the good stuff.

Comment: Question: Shouldn't it be lim n-->inf of n^2/nlogn? because if big-Ω is defined by f(n) >= c*g(n), then shouldn't we look for f(n)/g(n) >= c? Since it's division, I assume order matters...

Comment: It is not important. I mean, it depends on the expected result. If you want to calculate the limit for f(n)/g(n), then you need to obtain something > 0 (finite or infinite). If you want to calculate g(n)/f(n), you need to obtain something finite. Use f(n) = n and g(n) = n, n^2 and n^3 to see the differences.

Comment: So, calculating the lim of g(n)/f(n) as n->inf is to define g(n) as big-Oh of f(n) because it is bounded by it? and that proves that f(n) is Ω(g(n))? Did I get you right?

Comment: I'll try to add some details in my post. Regarding your photography, there are 2 useless steps ( just simplify by n ) because n is not 0.

Comment: The one thing I'm missing here is why you insist on finding the limit of nlogn/n^2 and not the other way around? and why do you need to use l'Hopital's Rule? isn't it enough to say that as n grows to infinity, the denominator overwhelms the numerator and the entire thing goes to 0?

Comment: 1) It's obvious without l'Hospital, but in terms of Math, when n->infinite, there is a indetermination `[infinite/infinite]`. This is why I removed that indetermination using l'Hospital.
-----------------------------
2) I don't insist to use `g(n)/f(n)`, both methods being similar. See the table above (I'll still edit it to become more clear). It's ok to use `f(n)/g(n)` if this is more obvious in terms of equivalence for those methods. Notice that the values O and Omega have the same values but in a different order, and Theta is an intersection.